# выбрать уникальные записи из таблицы

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Здравствуйте.

Существует база в которой хранятся записи, каждая запись имеет `meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`.

К примеру в `meta_id` хранится `id` записи в бд, в `post_id` - `id` записи из другой базы, которой принадлежит эта запись, в `meta_key` - ключ, в `meta_value` - значение ключа (Например: Вася: 6, Женя: 3, Вася: 2, Женя: 1, Олег:4, Витя: 3).

Нужно составить запрос, чтобы в результате получить: "Вася, Женя, Олег, Витя". Т.е. не нужно учитывать часть значения `meta_value`.

Моих знаний хватило на то, чтобы просто вывести все записи, которые мне нужны по определенному ключу, но проверка на уникальность происходит только по всему значению `meta_value`.

Вот пример моего запроса:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '$arom' AND post_id = '$id'";
```

Comment: Стоит пересмотреть структуру БД что бы поле можно было обрабатывать целиком (например изначально разделить на несколько полей). В данном случае вам надо используя строковые функции http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html вырезать нужную вам часть (например substr от начала строки до позиции ':')

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, думал о смене структуры, но к сожалению уже много записей в БД. Пришел к варианту `$result = substr($result, 0, strpos($result, ':', 0));`, а затем запись в массив и обработка массива.